# header data in python requests.put() does not change

Tags: python, python-requests, put

```
req2 = requests.put(url, json = json_data, headers= header)
print(req2.status_code)
print(req2.headers)
```

Where `json_data = req1.json()`

```
url = 'some url'
```

and

```
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/data;charset=UTF-16'}
```

In above code req1 gets a response from a server.  
`req1` json is passed with `url` to fetch response `req2`. I want to make `req2` using PUT() with `charset = utf-16`. When I am trying to do this by setting headers of req2 (1st line of code) it doesn't do anything as still the statement `print(req2.headers)` prints

```
{'Date': 'Thu, 01 Mar 2018 09:51:00 GMT', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct, req2.headers shows the response headers. You are setting the Content-Type of your request header, showing that the content you are sending is encoded in UTF-16. I don't think the response must have the same encoding as the request, it is up to the server to decide.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Accept-Charset` header to say what content type you wish to receive:

```
Accept-Charset: utf-8
```

The server can still ignore you. Usually it's not a problem as Requests will decode the response for you if you use the `response.text` field.